# FindItems() does not work in first run but works in the second run

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I am trying to fetch latest mail from my Outlook Exchange server mailbox using PowerShell. I have seen that the most common solution is to do a `FindItems()` method on the inbox object. However, I find that that running the code first time throws error stating

> Exception calling "FindItems" with "1" argument(s): "The request failed.

When I run it once again, the script completes successfully returning the last mail from my mailbox. In order to make it more clear, I wrote a script to execute the `FindItems()` method to execute twice in a `while` loop as shown below:

```
# bind to the Inbox folder of the target mailbox
$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($ews,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)

echo outsideWhile

$i = 0
while ($i -ne 2) {
    echo insideWhileBefore
    $inbox.FindItems(1)
    echo insideWhileAfter
    $i += 1
}
```

The first execution of `$inbox.FindItems(1)` fails but the second execution goes through fine returning the desired results.

The result output is as shown below

```
outsideWhile
insideWhileBefore
Exception calling "FindItems" with "1" argument(s): "The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (501)" ........
insideWhileAfter
insideWhileBefore
<MAIL CONTENTS>
insideWhileAfter
```

Please help me out in understanding why this happening so and how I can overcome it.

Comment: have you tried adding a delay? i wonder if there is a timing problem ... the 1st call may be occurring before the object is fully ready to be used.

Comment: Can you grab the inbox folderID lookup first, then bind for your $inbox folder with ($ews, $InboxFolderID)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey , @TEEKAY  - Thanking for helping out.

I tried both the comments but still the same issue. The below code shows the suggested changes.  



`$inboxFolderName =                               
 [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox`

Then i put a sleep of 5 seconds
 

`$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($ews,$inboxFolderName)`  

Again a wait of 5 seconds. Then below code
  
`$i=0  
while($i -ne 2){
 echo insideWhileBefore
 $inbox.FindItems(1)
 echo insideWhileAfter
 $i+=1
}`

Comment: @TechdeEnigma - unfortunately, i am out of ideas. [*sigh ...*] i have no access to the Outlook stuff since i run Thunderbird instead. i will go back to lurking ...